# tcpdf truetype unicode font install

Tags: php, fonts, tcpdf, truetype

I cannot convert this font (TrueType Unicode) for use in tcpdf. I'm using UTF-8 encoding

```
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14964998/chamberssansoffc.ttf
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14964998/chamberssansoffcb.ttf
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14964998/chamberssansoffcbi.ttf
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14964998/chamberssansoffci.ttf
```

This font works fine on me website - renders Chinese, Polish, German, Romanian characters.

I would be grateful for help.

Answer (score 1):

To see all UTF-8 encoding in tcpdf I will prefer use `freeserif` font.You can see a good example in tcpdf, example number 8.

Try this

```
$pdf->SetFont('freeserif', '', 12);
```

Now if you don't want to use freeserif, you can convert this font by tcpdf example by use this line.open tcpdf example folder, than open example __001, after 31 number line anywhere just past this code.Here make sure your path directory.Than run this code.After run go to font folder.You will get all your desire file.

`$fontname = $pdf->addTTFfont('/wamp/www/tcpdf/arial/arialuni.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);`

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know you can`t use ttf directly but you can search for font converter tcpdf or use this tool: http://fonts.snm-portal.com/. Helped me.

Comment: after converting fonts using this site i can only display Polish, German, English characters although me fonts contains Chinese and Romanian as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to load the fonts remotely. That wont work with TCPDF because it needs to write the the font directory in order to create the pseudo-files for the PDF. Try adding them locally:

```
$fontname = $pdf->addTTFfont('/path-to-font/chamberssansoffc.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);
```

Also, you have to make sure that the font folder is writable on the server to allow TCPDF to create the pseudo-files.

Hope this helps!

Comment: BTW the pseudo files are just the converted fonts, you don't want to delete them from the server either.

Comment: I have my fonts locally. I have posted theme here so that others can see what might be wrong with them